# Moving a file to another server via FTP using PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I need to move a backup of my database file to another server automatically using cron. I have some code and it's connecting to the ftp server fine, the problem is it will not move the file. I don't know how to make it show the exact error other than "FTP upload failed!" so I don't know what the real problem is, however, I believe it's got to do with the "real" path of the file on the server and/or the real path of the directory of the other server where it's placing the file.

Any help would be great.

```
$server = "MyServer"; 
$ftp_user_name = "MyUsername";
$ftp_user_pass = "MyPassword"; 
$source = "bumail_data/db-backup-05-09-15__17:23.sql"; 
$dest = 'db-backup-05-09-15__17:23.sql';

$connection = ftp_connect($server);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv ( $connection, true );
if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, FTP_BINARY);

if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close($connection);
```

The file $source is located in httpdocs/bumail_data/FILE.sql

The folder on the other server I want to put the file in is located before the public_html on a dir named dbbackup. So I guess that is the root dir but not sure.

I hope that helps you understand where the files are and what I maybe need to put in the script. I have tried everything I can think of from ../dir/file to var/host/root/dir/file and so on. It just will not move the file.

Comment: I should have noted as well that I am running this php script on the server where the .sql file is so it would move it to the other server. Don't know if that's my problem or not.

Comment: Usually, `ftp_put` should trigger a PHP error when something goes wrong. Please make sure that your PHP is configured to display or log error messages.

Comment: Perhaps, it also requires a fullpath of destination otherwise some configurations in .htaccess? Do check if server allows ftp too.

Comment: I don't have a clue how to turn on error reporting. I wish it was on it would save me a lot of trouble. The server is running plesk and it says under the PHP Settings: error_reporting: -2049, display_errors: on, log_errors: on

Comment: You can turn on error reporting on a per script basis by adding the following lines to the beginning of you script .....  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Try without the `:` into the filename

Comment: @Island Wave - thanks for that, it shows the error and I was able to fix the script to work. It was not finding the correct dir, which I figured was the problem, but I was just guessing until it was showing me the dir it was looking in. Thanks for the error reporting code!